# Converting tuple to int in python

Tags: python, sql, type-conversion

I have a query which returns a tuple and I'm trying to convert the first value from that tuple to a int but it always gives me this error: 
`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'`

I don't understand why it's doing this because the returned values looks like this: `[(25,)]`

Here is the code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT temp FROM temperatures WHERE datetimetest = ?", [datenow])
    currentTemp = cursor.fetchall()
    print(currentTemp) # this gives me [(25,)]
    convertedTemp = int(currentTemp[0])
```

Comment: `[(25,)]` is a list containing a tuple (1 length tuple) OF an int. do not try to convert, just access it using `var[0][0]`

Answer (score 6):

because `[(25,)]` is actually an int inside a tuple inside a list - so the correct call to get the int would be `currentTemp[0][0]`

Comment: Oh now i understand! I'm kind of new to python so i didn't knew that:( Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert list of tuples to list of integers

```
query = "some query that gets list of integers"
cursor.execute(query)
values = cursor.fetchall()

# values now looks like : [(1,), (2,), (3,)] 

i = 0
for v in values:
    values[i] = v[0]
    i += 1

# values now looks like : [1, 2, 3]
```